# Can we refactor these methods?

Tags: java, methods, refactoring, coding-style

I have classes with methods implemented as follow:

```
void methodOne() {
    try {
        getHelper().doActionOne();
    } catch ( Exception ex ) {
        throw new CustomException( ex );
    }
}

void methodTwo() {
    try {
        getHelper().doActionTwo();
    } catch ( Exception ex ) {
        throw new CustomException( ex );
    }
}

void methodThree() {
    try {
        getHelper().doActionThree();
    } catch ( Exception ex ) {
        throw new CustomException( ex );
    }
}


void methodFour;
void methodFive;
...
```

Is there a better way to do this? These codes make me uncomfortable.

**EDIT:**
Sorry for unclear example. I'm implementing GenericDao class with Hibernate, the real code is something like this:

```
class GenericDaoImpl<T, PK> {

    PK create( T object ) {
        try {
           getSession().save( object );
        } catch( Exception ex ) {
           throw new DataAccessLayerException( ex );// wrap any exception to my exception
        }
    }

   T read( PK id ) {
       try {
           getSession().get( T.class, id );
       } catch ( Exception ex ) {
           throw new DataAccessLayerException( ex );
       }

   }

  void update( T object );
  void delete( T object );

}
```

Comment: Could you please explain the context in which these methods are called?

Comment: Why does the code make you uncomfortable? I do not see anything particularly wrong with your code.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish, so it's hard to recommend a better way. Why are you catching all exceptions and wrapping them with a custom exception? It looks like perhaps you're trying to avoid all checked exceptions with an unchecked exception.

Comment: Your code looks perfectly valid for me, I do not see a reason to believe it should be refactored. Certainly, ideas can be suggested, but I doubt that it can be simpler than that.

Comment: Because the "steps" of the implementation are kinda repeat through methods, so I wanna to find a way to reduce the code-typing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a basic suggestion, but you could refactor this into something like a "Command Pattern."  This pattern allows you to encapsulate some functionality into a class that implements a single method.  The class can be instantiated and passed into another class to be executed, and the executor class doesn't have to know or care what it's doing, it just needs to call execute().  If the actions require arguments, the classes that implement Command can include fields/properties that can be set in the constructor or by standard property setters.

Make an interface like this (my Java is rusty, so this may not be 100% valid syntax):

```
public interface Command
{
    public void execute();
}

public class ActionOne implements Command
{
    public void execute()
    {
        // do actionOne...
    }
}

public class ActionTwo implements Command
{
    public void execute()
    {
        // do actionTwo...
    }
}

// etc. for more actions
```

Then create the class that executes the action, and the calling code just needs to pass in the correct Command implementation class.

```
public class Executor
{

    public void executeCommand(Command command)
    {
        try
        {
            // Put any boilerplate code here (logging, auditing, etc.)
            command.execute();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Put general error handling code here.  If you're just catching and rethrowing, consider not catching the Exception at this level.  If it's a checked exception, add a throws clause to the method.
            throw new CustomException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I appriciate your suggestion, but using Command Pattern seems increase the number of my classes. I'm considering using class Method to invoke dynamically.

Comment: Why do you care about increasing the number of classes?  10 small, focused classes are better than 1 big class that has to do 10 different things.  I would also steer clear of reflection unless you absolutely have to go that route.  Your code can be much more concisely expressed using some basic interfaces and classes.

Comment: I'm trying to refactor a class with the similar problem. 

Any further suggestions if my class has ~100 methods? The only thing I can think of is to create a new package for the Action classes.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can always refactor code.  The only issue is whether you're going to refactor to make it better or worse.  The hints that this code is odd, is a good hint that it can be made much better.

This looks like a good candidate for polymorphisim.  Instead of five different methods, try five different classes with one shared method.  The interface will tie it all together.

```
public interface DoIt {
  public void doIt();
}

public class One implements DoIt {
  public void doIt() {
    // code which was previously in getHelper.doActionOne();
  }
}

public class Two implements DoIt {
  public void doIt() {
    // code which was previously in getHelper.doActionTwo();
  }
}

...

public class Five implements DoIt {
  public void doIt() {
    // code which was previously in getHelper.doActionFive();
  }
}
```

Now the only thing is to create the right class for the situation, and call its `doIt()` method.

Answer (score 0):

This facility is provided by the [Spring Framework](http://www.springsource.org/about) along with many others. First, it has a specific `HibernateTemplate` which maps each Hibernate-specific exception to an unchecked, related Spring exception. Second, it provides an AOP service to translate exceptions at the method level so you can specify the mappings once and apply them uniformly across multiple services.

While I wouldn't use Spring for just this one feature, it has huge benefits for building applications and I have continued using it for many years.